# Using variables entered in one subprogram in another subprogram in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int display(int a)
{
    cout<<"enter a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a<<"  "<<a<<endl;
}

int display_three_times(int a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    float a;
    display(a);
    display_three_times(a);
    return 0;
}
```

By executing the program, I got something like this:
[Results of the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMuwk.jpg)
So my question is, how to use the variables in the second subprogram while they were entered in the first subprogram? I know it's a really basic question, but I do need help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the result of "display" into "display_three_times". You can do this by replacing

```
display(a);
display_three_times(a);
```

with

```
display_three_times(display(0));
```

and append `return a;` to the display function.

Some style tips. Why declare `a` as a `float` in main when you are only dealing with `int`? Since display doesn't take any input you could remove the parameter `int a` and declare it as a variable instead. `display` is perhaps misleadingly named since it also reads an integer. To avoid undefined behaviour also return an `int` from `display_three_times` or replace it with `void`; since we do not use the return value of `display_three_times` we may as well just change the return type to `void`. With these changes your program looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int read_and_display()
{
        int a;
        cout<<"enter a"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<a<<"  "<<a<<endl;
        return a;
}

void display_three_times(int a)
{
        cout<<a<<endl;
        cout<<a<<endl;
        cout<<a<<endl;
}

int main()
{
        int a=read_and_display();
        display_three_times(a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add a `return` to `display_three_times` or change it's return type to `void` to avoid undefined behaviour. The latter seems more reasonable here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply passing the variable, means you are passing its value(here 0) only. On passing the variable a in `display()` you are passing its value only. And inside display() function it is other independent variable 'a' which receives the value. And any change is will be in valid in its scope only inside the block of that function.
To use the same variable in another block you can pass the variable as a refrence variable.
And you can not type cast as int when you are passing it as refrence variable, because it means you are passing the exactly same variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int display(float &a)
{
    cout<<"enter a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a<<"  "<<a<<endl;
    return 0;

}

int display_three_times(float &a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float a;
    display(a);
    display_three_times(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add `return` statements to `display` and `display_three_times` or change their return-type to `void` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pass by reference or you can return the value from the first function and pass it to another function